# Jquery deferred and promises

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am new to jquery deferred and promises. I am trying to do this

```
var maxRes=function()
                {
                    var deferred=$.Deferred();
                      $("<img/>").attr("src", newurl).load(function(){
                             s = {w:this.width, h:this.height};
                             imgHeight =  this.height ;  
                             deferred.resolve();


                          }); 
                    return deferred.promise;
                }

                    maxRes().done(function(){


             if(imgHeight >=720)
                 {
                temp="...[HD]"
                 }
             else
                 {
                 temp = "...";
                 }
            console.log(temp);
                                       });
```

I keep getting this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d} has no method 'done'

Can somebosy please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deferred.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) is a method, you need to invoke it and return the value returned from `.promise()`

So

```
 return deferred.promise();
```

---

Again don't use closure/global objects to pass values from the async method to the callback. You can pass values to the done callback like

```
var newurl = '//placehold.it/256';
var maxRes = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $("<img/>").attr("src", newurl).load(function () {
        var s = {
            w: this.width,
            h: this.height
        };
        //pass the dimensions are arguments to the done callback
        deferred.resolve(s);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

maxRes().done(function (s) {
    //recieve the dimension as a parameter and use it instead of the shared variable

    //declare temp as a local variable instead of messing up the global scope
    var temp;
    console.log(s)

    if (s.height >= 720) {
        temp = "...[HD]"
    } else {
        temp = "...";
    }
    console.log(temp);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VT4HE/)

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes he is :)

Comment: Why rebundle properties of the image as `s` when you could simply `deferred.resolve(this)`? This and other simplifications [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VT4HE/3/)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot it was just a demo about how it should be done.... then for the sake of argument if we want to pass some custom processed attributes?