# Get notification after arbitrary set of jQuery functions have completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-deferred

I have a page that runs a very large set-up script, part of which depends on third-party extensions to jQuery & jQueryUI (in particular,  [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) & [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs)) as well as a suite of in house scripts. Between the using jQueryUI's tabs, DataTables reorganization & pagination of tables, and Foundation's application of styles after `$(document).ready()` there is an ugly period, between 1 and 4 seconds depending on the device, in which the page is visibly reshuffling.

I want to hide that by keeping a loading screen in front of everything until it's finished, but I'm not sure how to detect the completion.  In general, I know I need something like below (sorry I don't have verbatim code but it's huge and not helpful, this general form really should suffice):

```
// far away in another document that is in fact a collection of ~3k lines of code
var InHouseLibraryInstance = {
    events: {
         PageInitialized: jQuery.Event('PageIntitialized', {"bubbles": true, "cancelable": false, "eventPhase": 0, "type": 'PageIntitialized'});
    },
    init: function() {
         $(".using-data-tables").each(function() {
            $(this).dataTable();
         });
    }
}

// my actual loading script
var InHouseLibrary = new InHouseLibraryInstance();
$(document).on("PageInitialized", function() { $("#loadingScreen").hide();});

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* need to wrap these next two lines such that I can fire a custom 
       event—'PageInitialized' here, but any would do—when they've 
       completed */
    $(document).foundation();
    InHouseLibrary.init();

    /* Having detected the completion of the post-'ready'  rendering
       sequence, I want to fire an event (or, I suppose, execute a function,
       either is fine) */
    $(document).trigger("PageInitialized")
});
```

My sense is that this is what jQuery's deferred objects are for, but I after many hours and several tutorials, StackOverflow questions, etc.  don't know how to use them to achieve the described end. So a jQuery-based solution would be ideal, but isn't required.

**UPDATE:** My (still failing) attempt to implement the solution from @DavidTansey below:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var rendering = function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            deferred.resolve({
                InHouseLibrary: function() {
                    InHouseLibrary.init();
                 }, 
                Foundation: function() {
                  $(document).foundation();
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise();
    }

    rendering().done(function(status) {
        /* this is still reached well in advance of completing
           post-document-ready rendering */
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

If I understand things right, the reason this doesn't work is because `deferred.resolve()` is fulfilled as the encapsulated functions *fire* rather than when they complete. What I'd need is a way to know when the rendering they undertake has completed, ie. when DataTables has finished altering all the rows of the initialized tables, or when jQueryUI has completed reorganizing the page into tabs, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at this post as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316576/jquery-deferred-and-promises

Comment: @humble.rumble The problem is that it's not an AJAX issue, it's literally just a question of how fast this can execute; DataTables has to reorganize hundreds and hundreds of rows, jQueryUI has create tabs, etc.—it's *rendering* that's taking time, not waiting a reply from the server.

Comment: @DavidTansey I've tried things *like* this numerously, but the problem, for me, is that without callbacks that tell me when the rendering has completed, it's not clear what I'm deferring; I'll add my best attempt at interpreting this solution above